# How to hide and show the label inside a table?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have 3 tables called radio, song, and artist controlled by favorite.
Now I want to display different text for each table when there is nothing inside the table. But I want the text to be removed when there is something inside the table. I could display the text, by adding label into it.

```
if ([mainDataCenter.favoriteArtistArray count] == 0)
    {
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [label setText:@"AUCUN FAVORI DE FICHE ARTISTE"];
    }
    else
    {
        [label setHidden:YES];
    }
```

but after the text is hidden in one table ( meaning there is something added only to that particular table) but the other texts in other tables also disappeared.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{
    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    if (UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete == editingStyle) 
    {
        WebRadio *aRadio = [mainDataCenter.favoriteWebRadioArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [mainDataCenter removeWebRadioFromFavorite:aRadio];
        // Animate the deletion from the table.
        [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];       
    }
```

this is the code where I remove the things for the webradio table. ( the other 3 tables also the same)
I appriciate if anyone could help me in this problem I've been having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reusing the table cells across tables, then this might help:

```
if ([mainDataCenter.favoriteArtistArray count] == 0)
{
    [label setHidden:NO]; // show label if it was hidden
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setText:@"AUCUN FAVORI DE FICHE ARTISTE"];
}
else
{
    [label setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `if` `else` statement and it worked fine.